# Do we need to clear Integer and string variables?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Do we need to clear `Integer` and `string` variables?

I mean after we use integer variable, we have to make it zero also string variable have to clear for better memory performance and etc? or nothing happen?

**EDIT:**

For example this code is running 24h/7 in a server and don't turn off or restart server and calling this procedure more than 3000 time in 5 minute.

```
procedure somejob;
i:integer;
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4:string;
begin

 {Some more job....}
i := {BIG INTEGER};
Test1:= {BIG STRING};
Test2:= {BIG STRING};
Test3:= {BIG STRING};
Test4:= {BIG STRING};
{some more job....}


{we have to clear these variables or not?}

i:= 0;
Test1:= '';
Test2:='';
Test3:='';
Test4:='';
end;
```

Comment: No you don't need to clear variables for better performance. Typically. Depends on your code. Do you have any?

Comment: Generally, no, you don't need to zeroize either. Please add specific details to your question.

Comment: more explain and example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to clear any variables in that case.

Strings are [reference counted](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/String_Types_(Delphi)) in Delphi. That means that string will be freed automatically after execution of the routine.

Integer and other simple types are allocated in stack and disappear when running thread leaves the routine.